# Protein misfolding

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

Protein misfolding is usually prevented by molecular chaperons. Rarely, the chaperons are not able to prevent the misfolding as a result of which the infectous molecules called prions will form.

My question is, why does the misfolding occur like what are the reasons of misfolding and what kind of mechanism occurs? I somehow find limited information on this issue.

Comment: Prions only occur with specific proteins. Again please do some research before posting.

Comment: Your question is very broad. You can find entire review articles (or even books) dedicated to this topic. Please check out pubmed or Google scholar.

Comment: The astonishing thing is not that proteins misfold, but given the astronomical number of possible ways of folding they manage *not* to misfold. So you are coming at the problem with the wrong mindset. If you can access to it through a university library, try [this review](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/full/10.1146/annurev.genom.7.080505.115737?url_ver=Z39.88-2003&rfr_id=ori%3Arid%3Acrossref.org&rfr_dat=cr_pub%3Dpubmed).